# How to disable user input for materialize autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

Essentially, I want to force the user to be able to only select from the given values.

E.g when the user either selects or clicks inside the text box then it should display him/her some of the values (e.g Microsoft and google) and then he should be able to select either one of them or type a and then select apple but under no circumstances, he should be able to input or select anything that's not in the data/values.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/textech/pen/WNvrLMp

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete');
    var instances = M.Autocomplete.init(elems, {
      data: {
        "Apple": null,
        "Microsoft": null,
        "Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'
      },

    });
  });
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like materialize provides such functionality in the autocomplete component. What should be the behaviour of that input when the user introduces text that does not provide any option and ends the interaction with the input? Wouldn't it be better to use a `select` for your purposes?

Comment: In that case, it should want he user that input is invalid. I can use select but there are way too many values and it probably won't be a good UX.

Comment: @CaesarTex, have you found a solution to this? I am also stuck with the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing 'minLength: 0' into the initialisation brings up the options as soon as you click into the text field:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete');
    var instances = M.Autocomplete.init(elems, {
      data: {
        "Apple": null,
        "Microsoft": null,
        "Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'
      },
      minLength: 0,

    });
  });
```

Forked codepen:

https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/XWbXQZY

Documentation:

https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html#options

**EDIT**

I've added a listener to the autocomplete (jQuery but you can rework if necessary) - it hooks into the instance to check 'count', which is how many options are currently being returned. If this is 0 - ie no match - we clear the autocomplete.

I'll update the codepen :D

```
$('#autocomplete-input').on('keyup',function(){
  console.log('keyup')
   if ( instances[0].count === 0 ) {
     console.log('no matches');
     $('#autocomplete-input').val('');
   }
})
```

Comment: yes that solved one part of the equation but the main aprt of my question is how to disable user from entering their own text that's not in the suggestion or data list.

Comment: I see. I'm just looking at the autocomplete.js now. There isn't anything out of the box that will provide this for you. I think the quickest way would be to #1 create a unique array of all letters used in {data}, then #2 listen for the keyup, and if the keycode isn't matched in the array, return.

Comment: This does not work in a situation where user enters lets say "Test" but the dropdown option is "Test Company". Since the instance count would be 1, it allows user to input Test alone which is not in the dropdown